# SqlConnection() parameterless exception

Tags: c#, .net

I get this error trying to initialize SqlConnection instance.

First I tried with ConnectionString parameter, now I see it occurs even without it in the constructor. The code used to work, but fails after I changed my PC, so I suppose it has something to do with windows settings (windows 7) or user rights
My code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = 
   new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Server=server1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=db1");
   conn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
}
```

I already tried switching target framework back and forth as some suggest with no result (using 4.5.2 at the moment)

update

The exception thrown on the using line:

> System.TypeInitializationException occurred   HResult=0x80131534
>   Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'
>   threw an exception. Source=
>   StackTrace:  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()  at
>   Reg_CB_Report.Program.GetSql(String ExecText) in 
>   H:\MY\code\c#\Reg_CB_Report\Reg_CB_Report\Program.cs:line 228 at
>   Reg_CB_Report.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
>   H:\MY\code\c#\Reg_CB_Report\Reg_CB_Report\Program.cs:line 83
>
> Inner Exception 1: ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
>   (Exception from HRESULT:     0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

update2

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

tried recreating it - no result

StackTrace:

> StackTrace    "   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)\r\n   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)\r\n   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)\r\n   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)\r\n   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)\r\n   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)\r\n   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()"    string

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: Its type initializer [doesn't really do much](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,50), but it does attempt to access config. You'd think sufficiently broken config would stop your program completely but maybe worth looking through your config and seeing if there's anything suspect there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i'm not using it at all so it has only one tag with framework ver, already tried deleting it and recreating

Comment: Does the inner exception have a stack trace as well as a message?

Comment: Why do you create the connection object *before* the connection string? In fact, why use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` when you don't modify the initial connection string?

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos this is just my last try, i'm showing that ConnectionString has nothing to do, i may comment it out and still get the error

Comment: @Vadim this is actually the *first* try - it's not just *rare* to use the parameterless constructor, I can't even find [in the source code!](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data). `Integrated Security=SSPI;` was used a decade ago but should still work - `SSPI` was an API used for Windows authentication that is no longer used. Use `Trusted_Connection=True;`.

Comment: `..cctor()` is the *static constructor* though. That's another name for `The type initializer`. It means something is wrong on your machine, either in your app.config or the machine-wide `machine.config`. Mixed up client libraries perhaps?

Comment: Check [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,50) for the static constructor. It tries to find the `SqlColumnEncryptionEnclaveProviders` section. That's used for `Always Encrypted` connections. It was introduced in [.NET 4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#sqlclient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the latest version of the SqlClient NuGet package (4.6) on the oldest supported runtime. A missing security update may be involved as well.

The type initializer mentioned in the exception is the [static constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,50) which tries to load the `SqlColumnEncryptionEnclaveProviders` configuration section. I've never encountered that section either.

One option is to go back to an earlier SqlClient package that works. Another option is target .NET 4.7.2 and later. Finally, you can add the missing section yourself, as the link to the SharePoint bug shows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
       <section name="SqlColumnEncryptionEnclaveProviders" 
         type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlColumnEncryptionEnclaveProviderConfigurationSection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

This isn't the *only* bug introduced by SqlClient 4.6. There was another one, again involving the parameterless constructor.

Comment: it worked, but not straght away, the error shifted to conn.Open(), I installed the oldest nuget possible, tried everything actually, but after a reboot it started working